# Esp8266 esp01 kicks other devices off tplink router

Tags: esp8266, wifi

I had an Esp8266 esp01 module programmed to log onto the router and post data.  It worked fine for a few months but all of a sudden it kicks everyone else off the router.

Actually as soon as I connect the Esp and it connects to the ssid, it kicks off my laptop (laptop can no longer even see the ssid) and I see my Google home drop it's connection as well.  It's almost immediate, about 20 seconds after powering up my esp.  Seconds after I unplug the Esp google home comes back on and my laptop sees the ssid again.

What should I check for in my router?  It's a tplink tr-wl945N.

Comment: try to set RF TX power of the esp8266,

Comment: @Juraj what does that mean?  The Esp now has a dedicated power source.

Comment: in esp8266 sketch WiFi.setOutputPower(15.0);

Comment: I hope you didn't set the same IP address to the esp8266 as the computer has

Comment: I didn't set the ip, the router uses dhcp